# ASP.NET application loads in IE7 mode?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

Im currently having a problem, I have created an ASP.NET Web Forms Application but for some reason when debugging it loads it in IE7.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        HOLAAAAAAAAAA
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[IE7 even though I have IE11 installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4h5D.png)

EDIT: If I add  it loads in IE11 but im forcing it but im not attacking the problem.

Comment: To clarify, from your screen shot I'm guessing you mean in IE7 mode rather than IE7 itself?

Comment: Yes, correctly. It is loading with IE7 mode even though I have IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than likely that your policy for IE sets it to use IE7 compatibility mode by default, this is especially true in big corporate environments and they have old apps they can't update that need to run as if they were in IE7.

To get around this in the `<head></head>` tags add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Edge mode tells Windows Internet Explorer to display content in the highest mode available to it, so IE 11 would be 11, 8 would be 8 and so on.